# rspec match_array for empty array fails?

Tags: rspec

I can't use the `match_array` to match agains an empty array in one of my tests. I have the following message:

```
Failure/Error: expect(subject.custom_text_locations).to be match_array([])

   expected #<RSpec::Matchers::BuiltIn::MatchArray:105810100> => #<RSpec::Matchers::BuiltIn::MatchArray:0xc9d1168 @expected=[]>
        got #<Array:105810180> => []
```

Here is my test:

```
context 'when there is no custom text locations' do
  subject { create(:service, custom_text_locations: nil) }
  it 'returns empty list' do
    expect(subject.custom_text_locations).to match_array([])
  end 
end
```

If I change the `match_array([])` by `be_empty`, my code works. Also, as pointed by @PeterAlfvin, change `custom_text_locations` initialization on the subject to `[]` seems to work.

This is my method:

```
def custom_text_locations
  self[:custom_text_locations] || []
end
```

Question: What is wrong with my test?

Comment: That's odd. If you replace `subject.custom_text_locations` with `[]` does it pass?  If you print `subject.custom_text_locations.inspect` before the `expect`, what do you get?

Comment: Also, what version of RSpec are you using?

Comment: @PeterAlfvin You got it right, if I replace by `[]` it works. rspec version `2.14.7`. I'm adding the method also, since it seems to be involved the problem.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The code you posted is not the code that generated the error you posted.

The error you posted includes the incorrect `to be match_array([])` which is very different from the correct `to match_array([])` you have in your posted code.

Comment: Are you a seer or something? :O

Comment: I'm unaccepting your answer then I can award you some extra points with a bounty hunter.

Comment: Hardly a seer, more like a blind man. ;-) I'd been staring at and missing that difference for longer than I care to admit!

Comment: @fotanus Thanks, that's generous. :-)